# Wrong Excel Window in Focus after Workbook_Open

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

My recent upgrade to Office 365 / Excel 2016 has caused some unwanted behavioral changes.  Workbook("Portfolio Appreciation") contains a Workbook_open procedure which checks to see if Workbook("Index Returns") is open; if it is not, it will open that workbook.

With Excel 2007, `Index Returns` would open in the background and stay there, which is the desired behavior. It would be "in a window" and could be viewed, in the same Excel window, using the `Arrange All` option on the `Window` tab of the `View` ribbon.

With Excel 2016, if it gets opened by the Workbook_Open procedure, `Index Returns` opens in its own Excel Window, and winds up in front. (It can no longer be viewed in the same Excel window as `Portfolio Appreciation`).

The fact that `Index Returns` is in front is the problem.

I have tried selecting and deselecting the option to ignore other applications using DDE; I have tried the `AppActivate` method (shown in the code below) and verified, using a `MsgBox`, that the argument matches the relevant title bar.

Not sure where to go next.  Suggestions appreciated.

Also:  `Index Returns` contains no macros or connections.  `Portfolio Appreciation` contains no macros other than  `Workbook_Open` and does have a web query that gets refreshed when it opens (the query downloads some stock index stuff).

---

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wbs As Workbooks, wb As Workbook
    Dim IndexReturns As String
    Dim re As RegExp
    Const sPat As String = "(^.*\\DATA\\).*"
    Const sRepl As String = "$1EHC\Investment Committee\indexreturns.xlsb"
    Dim sTitle As String

sTitle = Application.Caption

Set wbs = Application.Workbooks
Set re = New RegExp
With re
    .Pattern = sPat
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
End With
IndexReturns = re.Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, sRepl)

For Each wb In wbs
    If wb.FullName = IndexReturns Then Exit Sub
Next wb

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wbs.Open (IndexReturns)
Set re = Nothing

AppActivate sTitle  'sTitle contains title of thisworkbook

'The below doesn't work either
'AppActivate ThisWorkbook.Application.Caption

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Comintern's code did not change the behavior, I focused on whether this was a timing issue, with `IndexReturns` not having an active window until after the code Activated the other workbook.  And code to adjust for this seems to have solved the problem.

I added a loop to test for the presence of a Window of `IndexReturns` before executing the `AppActivate` method.

```
Set wb = wbs.Open(IndexReturns)

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until wb.Windows.Count > 0

AppActivate sTitle
```

For good measure, I also made that window invisible, as I have no need to access it for other than debugging purposes:

```
wb.Windows(1).Visible = False
```

This seems to have solved the problem brought about by Excel 2016 opening files differently compared with 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I obviously can't test in your environment, but I'd try bypassing whatever Excel is doing and using a call to [BringWindowToTop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `AppActivate`:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal _
             hwnd As LongPtr) As Boolean
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal _
             hwnd As LongPtr) As Boolean
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias _
            "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, ByVal lpWindowName _
            As Any) As LongPtr
#Else
    Public Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal _
             hwnd As Long) As Boolean
    Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal _
             hwnd As Long) As Boolean
    Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias _
            "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, ByVal lpWindowName _
            As Any) As Long
#End If
```

Then...

```
    Dim hwnd As Long
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbEmpty, sTitle)    'sTitle contains title of thisworkbook
    BringWindowToTop hwnd     
    '...or...
    SetForegroundWindow hwnd
```

Comment: Thanks for advice.  I did try it, and it did not change the behavior.  However, it led me to do some testing which pointed to a timing issue.  See my answer.